# OpenCV PinholeCameraModel undefined reference

Tags: ros, kinect, opencv, ir

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to the the camera model information by using:

void cameraModel_cb(const sensor_msgs::CameraInfoConstPtr &info_msg)
{
image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel model_;
model_.fromCameraInfo(info_msg);
fx = model_.fx();
fy = model_.fy();
}

Where info_msg is /camera/depth_registered/camera_info from the openni.launch node. I need the IR camera focal lenght in order to get range images using:

range_image_.setDepthImage(depthImage,depth_msg->width, depth_msg->height, (depth_msg->width)/2, (depth_msg->height)/2, fx, fy, angular_resolution_);

The problem is that I keep getting this error:

CMakeFiles/keypointsplanar.dir/src/keypointsplanar.o: In function `cameraModel_cb(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)': /home/jumpei/fuerte_workspace/tesis/src/keypointsplanar.cpp:26: undefined reference to` image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel::PinholeCameraModel()'
/home/jumpei/fuerte_workspace/tesis/src/keypointsplanar.cpp:27: undefined reference to `image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel::fromCameraInfo(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_std::allocator<void > const> const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

when trying to compile my program. I linked the libraries in the CMakeList file like this:

FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )
rosbuild_add_executable (keypointsplanar src/keypointsplanar.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( keypointsplanar ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} )

I'd really appreciate some help with this problem, thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39783/opencv-pinholecameramodel-undefined-reference/) by [David Bravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2917/david-bravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need to add the `image_geometry` package to your `manifest.xml` as a dependency.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-03-10**:
It worked for me..thanks